# Using Redux Toolkit with large arrays storing lat, long coordinates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, mapbox, redux-toolkit

I'm working with React Native / Redux Toolkit to record and track an user's location on a map. Whenever the user moves > 2meters, redux dispatch is fired and the updated coordinates are pushed to the allCoords array. Assuming the user is moving, this happens at ~ 1fps (once per second). Naturally this is creating a very large array of coordinates [lat, long] and the performance of the app comes to a complete standstill after about 5 minutes. This only happens on a physical device... works just fine on the sim.

I'm having major performance issues, I believe due to 2 main problems (excuse my ignorance here to other likely glaring problems):

1. The way I'm handling the large arrays and pushing the new coordinates to the array in Redux. I *believe* that simply using .push() inside the reducer abides by proper redux toolkit procedure for usage with Immer. I was previously using a spread ...newCoords, but looks like redux toolkit wants a .push() as I have it for Immer?
2. The MapView component that renders the large array (allCoords). As the user's location is tracked for multiple minutes -> hours, the array size is very large for the component to dynamically be updating. Would doing some sort of split be beneficial or is the size of the array not as big of a deal as I think it is? But after 5 minutes the array size would be only a couple hundred elements, which doesn't seem overly large?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

recordSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export const RouteRecord = createSlice({
  name: "routeRecord",
  initialState: {
    currentRouteCoordinates: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    logCoords: (state, action) => {
      { ...... }

      let lat = action.payload.coords.latitude
      let long = action.payload.coords.longitude
      let alt = action.payload.coords.alt
      let newCoords = [long, lat, alt]

      state.currentRouteCoordinates.push(newCoords)
      
      { ...... }
    },
  },
})

export const { logCoords } = RouteRecord.actions
export default RouteRecord.reducer
```

mainStore.js

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import {
  FLUSH,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  persistReducer,
  persistStore,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
  REHYDRATE,
} from "redux-persist"
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage"

import RouteReducer from "../features/recordSlice"
{ ...... }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  record: RouteReducer,
  { ...... }
})

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  blacklist: [
    { ...... }
  ], 
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
export default store
```

routelines.js

```js
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native"
import React from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"
import { ShapeSource, LineLayer } from "@rnmapbox/maps"

const RouteLines = () => {
  const allCoords = useSelector((state) => state.record.allCoords)

  return (
    <ShapeSource
      id="source2"
      // tolerance={1}
      shape={{
        type: "MultiLineString",
        coordinates: allCoords,
      }}
    >
      <LineLayer id="layer2" style={styles.lineLayer} />
    </ShapeSource>
  )
}

export default RouteLines
```

Comment: It doesn't matter with the data, check with Map, that might be causing the issue.. May be you should use clusters to reduce load on the Map.

Comment: I was just trying clusters and buffers a minute ago. Seemingly clusters are only for point features, not line features. I reduced the coordinate precision from 8 decimal points to 6 and that helped a bit. But still running into the same issue around 5-6min.

Answer (score 0):

I changed map providers and now having zero issues, app runs 60fps without a hiccup and I didn’t make any changes to the OP code. The prior map library was mapbox based (RNmapbox):

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiNyYfK-8n4AhW5KkQIHVbZAp8QFnoECAIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frnmapbox%2Fmaps&usg=AOvVaw2CYQAzU___f6_8A1P8o8cE

And now I’m using react native maps:

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps

There are some sacrifices in doing so, no 3D and terrain layers for example… but it’s running well so going to stick with this for now.